# unexpected non void return value in void function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, asynchronous, closures

I've been pouring over stack overflow for ages trying to find a way out of this error:

> unexpected non void return value in void function

that I am getting with returning a `Bool` within my function.

i just can't seem to dig my way out of this one.  I'm sure its something to do with async but I'm not very familiar with these types of functions.

```
class CheckReachability {


    class func setupReachability (hostName:String?, useClosures: Bool) -> Bool{

        var reachability : Reachability!
        var connected = false

                let reachability2 = hostName == nil ? Reachability() : Reachability(hostname: hostName!)
                reachability = reachability2
                try! reachability?.startNotifier()

                if useClosures {
                    reachability2?.whenReachable = { reachability in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            connected = true
                            print("Reachable....")
                        }
                    }
                    reachability2?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            connected = false
                            print("Not Connected....")
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("reachabilityChanged:")), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability2)
                }
            return connected
            }

}
```

calling this from viewdidload on another vc doesn't allow enough time to get a true result

```
        let connected = CheckReachability.setupReachability(hostName: nil, useClosures: true)
if connected {
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give me that error. Check for unbalanced { } in code not shown

Comment: What exactly do you want to reach? Each time when reachability status changes to know it?

Comment: you are correct I've been looking at this too long.  Problem i now have is initialising the function from my viewDidLoad in another VC with doesn't allow enough time return a true result.  added some details on edit.

Comment: yes pretty much the change in reachability.  I'm trying to initialise it in viewdidload in another viewcontroller but because its asynchronous its not allowing enough time to actually get a true result

Comment: It's derived from the well-liked and famous issue [returning data from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a checking class to listen to the reachability, define it as a singleton and pass the completeBlock to it like this:

```
class CheckReachability {

    static let shared = CheckReachability()

    var reachability: Reachability?

    func setupReachability(hostName:String?, completeBlock: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        reachability = hostName == nil ? Reachability() : Reachability(hostname: hostName!)

        try? reachability?.startNotifier()

        if let block = completeBlock {
            reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Reachable....")
                    block(true)
                }
            }
            reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Not Connected....")
                    block(false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If we don't use block, there is no point to observe it.
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: .ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        }

    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func reachabilityChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        // ?? what should we do here?
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and apologies for the scrappy original post.  i had been staring at it for hours and i wasn't thinking clearly.  I am having trouble understanding the singleton and completion block approach.  i can see that you only want something like this to run once and then notify if there is a change, but i can't figure out how to access the result from other classes?  am i going to have to go down the delegation path here?

Comment: originally i just had this being called from viewdidload in one viewcontroller and it would always update the variable connected when there was a change in the connection which would then let me either fetch data from network or local store.

Comment: You can take a look on this library: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, it contains a NetworkReachabilityManager to help to detect the Reachability. In your view controller, declare the iVar of this class (e.g. named `manager`), then call `manager?.startListening()` and set `manager?.listener = ...` on your `viewDidLoad` , `manager?.stopListening()` on `deinit`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing because the code you posted does not have the error you describe. However, you're trying to create a function that returns a result from an async function. That is not how async works.

Async functions start to do a task in the background, where that task won't be finished before it's time to return.

You need to adjust your thinking. Instead of trying to return a result from your function, you need to write your function to take a completion handler. You then call the completion handler once the long-running task has finished (which is after your function has returned.)

@bubuxu provided you with code showing how to modify your function as I described.